# Helicon ISAPI rule to rewrite a old url to new one and check query string pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have the following url which i want to write a helicon RewriteRule rule 
it should check the pattern startat=/mypage.asp and then only execute

Original url

http://www.test.com/welcome.asp?startat=/mypage.asp&value1=23&value2=3434&value3=1&value4=someothervalue

the new url

http://www.test.com/mynewpage.hcx?startat=/mypage.asp&value1=23&value2=3434&value3=1&value4=someothervalue

as i am new to helicon and regex ,can someone help me

appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

RewriteRule ^/welcome.asp(.+)$ /mynewpage.hcx$1 [RP]

Will match any url starting with /welcome.asp, and $1 will contain the rest of the url.

Not sure about the [] part, but RP is permanent redirect (aka, 301)

EDIT: You could try this:

RewriteRule ^/welcome.asp(.*startat=/mypage.asp.*)$ /mynewpage.hcx$1 [RP]

.* <- 0 or more chars
.+ <- 1 or more chars

so basically it translates to: 
start with /welcome.asp, 0 or more chars followed by "startat=/mypage.asp", followed by 0 or more chars until end of url.

Redirect to mynewpage.hcx followed by any content from the first paranthesis.